# determinant inequality, $AB=BA$, then $ \det(A^2+B^2)\ge \det(2AB) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

$A$ and $B$ are two  $n\times n $ real matrices, $AB=BA$.  Can we conclude that

$$ \det \Big(A^2+B^2\Big)\ge \det(2AB) $$

is right?

Well, the inequality is interesting. if $A,B$ are upper triangular matrices, it is obvious right. If $AB\ne BA$, $ \det \Big(A^2+B^2\Big)\ge \det(AB+BA) $ is wrong.

Comment: It suffices to check for complex upper-triangular matrices .. since, $AB=BA$ it follows $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously upper triangulizable.

Comment: @r9m The eigenvalues are not necessarily real. Your proof only works when the eigenvalues are real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is NO. Take for example $A=I_2$ and

$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

We then have $B^2=-I_2$, $A^2+B^2=0$ and $2AB=2B$,
so ${\sf det}(A^2+B^2)=0$ and ${\sf det}(2AB)=4$.

Comment: so, for $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$,  there also exist counter-example

Comment: @ziangchen Indeed. Take $A=I_n$ and $B=$ the matrix made of two blocks, $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ and $I_{n-2}$.